# Sort NSArray of NSDictionaries by string date in key?

Tags: ios, sorting, date, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have been struggling to find an easy way to sort an NSMutableArray that contains NSDictionaries. Each NSDictionary has a key named "Date" which contains an NSString of a date (ex: 10/15/2014).

What I am looking to do is sort the array based on those strings in ascending order.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

    NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:s1];
    NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:s2];

    return [d1 compare:d2]; // ascending order
    return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
}
```

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"interest"  ascending:YES];
    stories=[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
    recent = [stories copy];
```

Each way results in a crash and I think it is because it is a NSString instead of a NSDate but I am just at a loss on how to do this.

Can anyone show me the correct way to accomplish this?

This is how I call the first block of code:

```
theDictionaries = [[theDictionaries sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: What line does it crash on, and what is the error message?

Comment: With the first block of code it crashes on NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:s1]; with the crash being: NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a dictionary to a string parameter (s1). Show the code for the whole method. Where do s1 and s2 come from?

Comment: I updated the bottom of my question to include how I call the method. Besides that, that is all I do to sort the method. Is there something I am just not seeing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to get the strings inside your dictionaries. It looks like you're trying to compare the dictionaries themselves. If you had an array called data, you would do something like this,

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

self.data = [self.data sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1[@"date"]];
    NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2[@"date"]];

    return [d1 compare:d2]; // ascending order
    return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
}];

NSLog(@"%@",self.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort using Model Class then you must use it.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];

finalCompleteArray = [finalCompleteArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MessageChat *obj1, MessageChat *obj2) {
                        NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1.LastDate];
                        NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2.LastDate];

                        NSLog(@"[d1 compare:d2] %ld",(long)[d1 compare:d2]);
                        NSLog(@"[d2 compare:d1] %ld",(long)[d2 compare:d1]);
                        return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
                    }];
        NSLog(@"%@",finalAssignedArray);
```

- Using **finalCompleteArray** is **MutableArray**
- Using **MessageChat** is Object **Model Class** File
- Using **obj1.LastDate** is Object Model Class **Variable**